# Add more UICollectionViewCell to an existing UICollectionView

Tags: xcode, ios6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to add some more cells to an existing `UICollectionView`, which is already filled with some cells.

I tried to use the CollectionView `reloadData` but it seems to reload the entire collectionView and I just wanted to add more cells.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to insert new cells to the **UICollectionView** without having to reload all its cell is by using the **performBatchUpdates**, which can be done easily by following the steps below.

```
// Lets assume you have some data coming from a NSURLConnection
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *erro)
{
      // Parse the data to Json
      NSMutableArray *newJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

      // Variable used to say at which position you want to add the cells
      int index;

      // If you want to start adding before the previous content, like new Tweets on twitter
      index = 0;

      // If you want to start adding after the previous content, like reading older tweets on twitter
      index = self.json.count;

      // Create the indexes with a loop
      NSMutableArray *indexes = [NSMutableArray array];

      for (int i = index; i < json.count; i++)
      {
            [indexes addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0]];
      }

      // Perform the updates
      [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{

           //Insert the new data to your current data
           [self.json addObjectsFromArray:newJson];

           //Inser the new cells
           [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:indexes];

      } completion:nil];
 }
```

Comment: this method disappears previous cells then load again and scrolls collectionView to the top.

Answer (score 6):

The `UICollectionView` class has methods to add/remove items. E.g., to insert an item at some `index` (in section `0`), modify your model accordingly and then do:

```
int indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:index];
NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath inSection:0];
[collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
```

The view will do the rest.

Comment: So, when i first use `[UICollectionView reloadData]` i should save the  index of the last Cell used, and then, when i call the method to add more cells i should use its latest cell indexPath, correct? @chris

Comment: You don't need `[UICollectionView reloadData]` at all when adding items. Just do `insertItemsAtIndexPaths:` and make sure that subsequent calls to your data source' methods `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:` and `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` reflect your changes.

Comment: I did it at first it worked. But, when the new cells will be show on the display i get the message: 

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (36) beyond bounds (36)'` 

@chris do you know what i did wrong?

Comment: This is the line i coded:
`NSMutableArray *indexes = [NSMutableArray array];         
            
            for (int i = 0; i < [_jsonLista count]; i++)
            {
                NSIndexPath *index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:([Collection numberOfItemsInSection:0]) + i inSection:0];
                
                [indexes addObject:index];
            }
            
            [Collection insertItemsAtIndexPaths:indexes];`

Comment: You have to adjust your model before updating the view.

Comment: I changed the numberOfItemsInSection to the new value, which is 72 now. Is that it? @Chris

`- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{    
    return [_totalGrid intValue];
}`